# Angular директива не получает значение атрибута, а значение есть

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте. Директива не отрабатывает как положено. Код директивы совсем простой.

```
user.directive('avatar', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<img class="avatar" src="" alt="avatar" />',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs){
        element.find('img').attr('src', attrs.avatar);
    }
};
});
```

В консоле видно:
[image: консоль]

В код вставляется адрес картинки, но директива его не принимает.
[image: Исходник]

В первом случае директива отрабатывается (успешно) из контроллера userCtrl, во втором случае из родительского контроллера. В исходнике в обоих случаях виден адрес картинки. Почему директива его не забирает в одном случае?

Если же в шаблоне директивы прописать непосредственно

```
template: '<img class="avatar" src="{{user.avatar}}" alt="avatar" />',
```

Тогда картинка отображается, но такой вариант лишает абстракции.
[jsfiddle.net/t2yaLdq6/7](http://jsfiddle.net/t2yaLdq6/7)

**Дополнение:**
Проблема решена. В родительском контроллере директива исполняется прежде, чем значение присваивается переменной. Решить можно добавив следующий код:

```
    scope.$watch(attrs.avatar, function(val){
            element.find('img').attr('src', val);
        });
```

Stepan Kasyanenko предложил более правильное решение в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходим пример кода, показывающий, как Вы используете директиву `avatar`. Ваша директива успешно работает на тестовом [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/t2yaLdq6/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.urlImage = "https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.png";
  })
  .directive('avatar', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<img class="avatar" src="" alt="avatar" />',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find('img').attr('src', attrs.avatar);
      }
    };
  });;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <h2>
    Статичная картинка
    </h2>
    <div avatar="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.png"></div>
    <h2>
    Картинка с переменной
    </h2>
    <div avatar="{{urlImage}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Обновление.

После представления примера не работающего кода с проблемой ,проблема понятна.

Проблема была в обновлении переменной в директиве . Вы имеете два контроллера: родительский и дочерний. В дочернем контроллере вы меня переменную, используемую в родительском. На момент создания директивы в родительском контроллере, переменная еще не инициализирована. Соотвественно, вам надо в директиве реагировать на изменение переменной. Есть много способов это сделать, но самый лучший - использовать изолированный `scope`.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vfnv0zu/) .

```js
angular.module('ParentApp', ['ExampleApp'])
  .controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
  });

angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    var data = {};
    data.user = {
      urlImage: "https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.png"
    };
    angular.extend($scope.user, data.user);

  })
  .directive('avatar', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        avatar: "@"
      },
      template: '<img class="avatar" src="{{avatar}}" alt="avatar" />',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        //element.find('img').attr('src', attrs.avatar);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ParentApp">
  <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <h2>Картинка в родителе</h2>
    <div avatar="{{user.urlImage}}"></div>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <h2>Картинка с переменной</h2>
      <div avatar="{{user.urlImage}}"></div>
      <div>
        <img src="{{user.urlImage}}" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. простите за форматирование, пишу с мобильного.

Comment: У меня она тоже работает, но только в одном контроллере. В родительском не хочет. Вот написал как у меня реализовано https://jsfiddle.net/t2yaLdq6/7/

Comment: @Grundy директива отрабатывает верно, но не везде. А надо что бы везде работала.

Comment: Вот вариант, в котором видно, что значение в родительском доступно. Но в директиву почему-то не попадает.

Comment: @fedornabilkin я обновил мой ответ.  Пожалуйста, обновите ваш вопрос, добавьте в него пример кода, показывающий проблему и ссылку на jsfiddle.

Comment: @fedornabilkin :-D так-то ответ не я писал

Answer (score 1):

Так как при установке значения используется интерполяция

```
avatar="{{user.urlImage}}"
```

то в методе link значение еще не установлено. Чтобы отследить изменение таких атрибутов можно использовать [$observe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe)

```js
angular.module('ParentApp', ['ExampleApp'])
  .controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
  });

angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    var data = {};
    data.user = {
      urlImage: "https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.png"
    };
    angular.extend($scope.user, data.user);

  })
  .directive('avatar', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<img class="avatar" src="" alt="avatar" />',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('avatar', function(avatar) {
          element.find('img').attr('src', avatar);
        });

      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ParentApp">
  <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <h2>Картинка в родителе</h2>
    <div avatar="{{user.urlImage}}"></div>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <h2>Картинка с переменной</h2>
      <div avatar="{{user.urlImage}}"></div>
      <div>
        <img src="{{user.urlImage}}" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что же в итоге использовать? Изолированный scope, $watch или $observe? Что будет работать быстрее и экономичнее?

Comment: @fedornabilkin, зависит от приложения, все примерно равнозначно